# MySQL : Copy all databases from one server to another

Tags: mysql, database, migration, database-migration

I am working on migrating one of our project which requires MySQL to another server. I am looking for a way to migrate all the created databases by the users to another server. For starting, I tried out to move only one database, but it's not working.

Attempt :

```
mysqldump db_name | mysql -h root@migration_server.com target_db(same name);
```

Error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'command as above' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Anything on the 2nd server I need to set or something else. Thank you.

Comment: Create your dump first and then import it with a separate command line instruction.

Comment: @Shadow : How, can't I just push one database at a time?

Comment: At the moment you do not see the output of the 1st command (mysqldump). If you ran it separately, then you would probably know what's the output from the 1st one that causes a problem with the 2nd one. My initial guess: you do not provide login details for the mysqldump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking Dump.

```
  mysqldump -uroot -p --port= <3306 or 3309> db_name > "d:\target_db.sql";
```

restoring dump

```
mysqldump -uroot -p  db_name < "d:\target_db.sql";
```

Mentioning port is optional.

Comment: I think I will create the dump on the system and then transfer it manually as mysql is having problems connecting to the migrating server, error : 2005: Unknown MySQL server host . Can I just remove the server parameters and get a dump.

Comment: First command worked, now working on migration, will keep you updated. Thanks.

Comment: Your 2nd command is not working somehow even with port specified, ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root -p --port=3306 shopware < /root/target_db.sql' at line 1

Comment: are you missing double ticks around directory path ??

Comment: @WeareBorg You seem to be issuing the 2nd command **within** mysql's command line client, not from the command prompt.

Comment: Thank you, the commands seem to be working now, I am trying to copy also mysql database, but the mysqldump command is skipping the tables, mysql database has around 251 tables, and its only copying 24... Any ideas... so messy this is...

Comment: I had to take backup of all databases, then only remaining or skipped tables will be copied, ideally mysqldump should show such warnings that its skipping around 200 tables... Thank you for your help.. :-)